# About me section on Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

The SO CV have always had the "Personal statement" section. However, I really feel like that doesn't work really well for a "About me"-style 6~8 line paragraph on the Developer Story. This leads to a situation where I want to have different Personal Statements for the each one of the two views.

And, of course, there is no substitute for that in the Developer Story. There is nowhere I can write an "About me" paragraph. So I was thinking: maybe the current Personal Statement should be moved somewhere else in the DS (to a less intrusive position) and a new section should replace what the Personal Statement is in the DS today?